# Spotify and Skype Business sound breaking on Lenovo T430 upon CPU load

Tags: windows-7, audio, skype, thinkpad, spotify

Spotify and Skype Business sound is breaking badly on Lenovo Thinkpad T430 laptop anytime when there is significant CPU load (25% or more). For example browsing files or running Eclipse searches or indexing cause bad stutter. Windows 7 64 bit professional. I have had this problem for a few months and have been desperately looking for help.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a fix for this from:
[Mouse is unresponsive when the computer is busy](https://superuser.com/questions/773588/mouse-is-unresponsive-when-the-computer-is-busy/1198602)

VeganCaramels answer worked:

> Start > Run > msconfig > click Boot tab > click Advanced Options >
>   make sure "Number of processors" shows the number of cores your
>   processor actually has (change it to the correct number if it's wrong)

I have Intel i5-520M dual core CPU so I set the "Number of processor" to 2.
The problems disappeared immediately after reboot. 
My computer also speeded up significantly, for example Eclipse search is now at least 2-3x faster for same codebase.

I suspect this has got to do with some bug in Hyperthreading support, I have enabled it in BIOS for Virtualbox purposes.